# GPO policy for Enhanced Storage Access

Tags: windows, group-policy

#GPO #usb
Hi,
Has anyone ever configured a GPO policy for Enhanced Storage Access'?

I'm trying to set it so that only users use the dedicated flash drive list. Unfortunately despite specifying "vendorid-productid" in "configure list devices usable on your computer" exceptions do not apply.

https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.EnhancedStorageAccess::ApprovedEnStorDevices

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lywrm.png)

Answer (score 0):

"Enhanced Storage devices" are not just flash drives.

Enhanced Storage devices are special devices that support the IEEE 1667 protocol to provide functions such as authentication at the hardware level of the storage device. You can use the GPO to control access to those cpecial devices, not for "general" USB-Storage devices.

Setting the GPO will have no effect on non-IEEE1667 devices. Visit the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/enstor/about-enhanced-storage) for more information on that.